# Django app on Heroku - PythonPath Issue

Tags: python, django, heroku, pythonpath

I'm trying to configure my django app on Heroku for the first time.  I've made it to the point of pushing my code to "heroku master", but I'm getting a `ModuleNotFound` error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UsefulFunctions'`

Here's the full trace:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 390, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (251/251), done.
Writing objects: 100% (390/390), 56.56 KiB | 2.83 MiB/s, done.
Total 390 (delta 205), reused 262 (delta 122)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting django (from -r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading Django-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2 (from -r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.7.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
remote:        Collecting python-decouple (from -r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading python-decouple-3.1.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting django-debug-toolbar (from -r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading django_debug_toolbar-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (206kB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow (from -r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading Pillow-5.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
remote:        Collecting pytz (from django->-r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.0 (from django-debug-toolbar->-r /tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: pytz, django, psycopg2, python-decouple, sqlparse, django-debug-toolbar, Pillow
remote:          Running setup.py install for python-decouple: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for python-decouple: finished with status 'done'
remote:        Successfully installed Pillow-5.1.0 django-2.0.4 django-debug-toolbar-1.9.1 psycopg2-2.7.4 python-decouple-3.1 pytz-2018.4 sqlparse-0.2.4
remote:
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
remote:          """)
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
remote:            app_config.import_models()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
remote:            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_9b6fcbcef79c70d29d429c430e653020/users/models.py", line 4, in <module>
remote:            from UsefulFunctions.dbUtils import *
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UsefulFunctions'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to salty-savannah-12027.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/salty-savannah-12027.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/salty-savannah-12027.git'
```

**App structure**

[image]

I tried all kinds of futzing around to get it to recognize my PYTHONPATH in my `<app>/lib` directory, but no luck:

http://blog.sionide21.com/posts/2014/01/managing-pythonpath-on-heroku/
https://www.biggleszx.com/2012/03/your-first-heroku-django-app/

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an import issue.  My original import line:

```
from UsefulFunctions.dbUtils import *
```

Python couldn't locate `UsefulFunctions` since my `PYTHONPATH` variable was reset.  So, I changed it to an absolute import:

```
from lib.UsefulFunctions.dbUtils import *
```

This article helped:

https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing your PYTHONPATH to include the file, why not put UsefulFunctions in your existing PYTHONPATH? Django apps often conventionally have a `utils` module (`utils.py`) for such things. If it's specific to your Users app, you can put it at `users/utils.py`, but if you need it more generally, it can be outside the app, next to `manage.py` in the project.

That said, if you do want to keep it outside the project root and app dirs, I'm noticing that UsefulFunctions does not have a .py extension, so you'll have to make it a .py file at the very least.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I just put the UsefulFunctions package in a "lib" directory to keep things organized.  Not sure what the standard way of doing it is.  It works fine locally, but I still can't get it to work with Heroku.

Comment: Oh, got it. I didn't see before from the screenshot that it was a directory, so obviously those parts of my comment that assume it's one file are useless. I'm not sure what Heroku likes or doesn't about editing the PYTHONPATH directly, but you can also try editing `sys.path` from within your python code (at the beginning of your settings should work fine), or you could move the directory out of `lib`--one directory in the app root called `UsefulFunctions`, or one directory called `lib` are at least the same amount of clutter.

Comment: Not your fault...I updated the picture after the original post :)  You're right, I could move UsefulFunctions out, but then if I add more packages, I'd run into the same issue.  That's why I put them in the `lib` directory.  Thanks for the suggestions.